# ¿Cómo llamar funciones de Javascript usando Delphi?

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, navegador-web

Hola me he hecho un pequeño navegador que tendrá la siguiente apariencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Button5: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Web: TWebBrowser;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    procedure Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Web.GoBack;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Web.GoForward;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Web.GoHome;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Web.Navigate(Edit1.Text);  
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Web.Refresh;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Caption := 'WEB BROWSER' + Web.LocationName;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'WEB BROWSER' + Web.LocationURL;
end;

end.
```

Pero ahora lo que quiero es llamar a la función del javascript desde este html de ejemplo que uso que es el siguiente:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ExecScript example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
      function SetFont(fontname) {
        document.body.style.fontFamily = fontname;
      }
    // -->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Document</h1>
    <p>Select a font above to change the font displayed in this document</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Veo muchos ejemplos por internet pero son demasiado complejos para mí. Lo que quiero es que cuando visito mi delphi llame a `la funcion javascript` que es `SetFont` y que cuando la llame sea por lo menos capaz de cambiar el fondo de la pagina.

Un ejemplo de lo que intento:

[Fuente](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=21)

Pero es de vital importancia que lo adapte al ejemplo propuesto usar una variable para guardar la funcion `javascript` del html y luego ejecutarla usando `HTMLWindow.execScript`.

Comment: El que puedas ejecutar javascript depende de que el motor/visor html que estés usando incluya un motor de javascript. Aparte de eso,  debes llamar a la función SetFont desde dentro de tu código html (directamente desde un bloque script o desde un evento), sino no te funcionará en ningún navegador

Comment: si aqui vi un ejemplo http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=21 por lo que es posible lo estoy intentando adaptar a mi ejemplo llamar simplemente la función usando mi ejemplo.

Comment: Luego de leer tu pregunta, no comprendo bien. ¿Tu quieres que se llame a una función `js` desde el código Delphi, por ejemplo al hacer clic en un botón fuera del navegador? o ¿cuándo?. No comprendo también qué tiene que ver la variable que mencionas al final. No hay forma de almacenar en una variable la función como tal (javascript no está compilado, no puedes tener un apuntador al código máquina, por ejemplo, como si podrías hacerlo con una variable tipo función en Delphi).

Comment: En el ejemplo fuente  que puse lo hace y funciono. la pagina se cargará en mi navegador que hice con delphi y cuando se cargue yo llamare a la función javascript de la pagina tal como hizo en el ejemplo de la fuente que puse.

Comment: ¿Entonces solucionaste ya tu problema? Si es así, estaría bien que añadieras una respuesta (y la marcases como aceptada) para que pueda servir de referencia a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 1):

El ejemplo que ves en delphidabbler es prácticamente lo que necesitas, solo hacía falta cambiar el nombre del método y usar solo una variable.

```
procedure TForm1.CallSentFont(S: string);
  { Calls JavaScript SentFont() function }
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;      // current HTML document
  HTMLWindow: IHTMLWindow2; // parent window of current HTML document
  JSFn: string;             // stores JavaScipt function call
begin
  // Get reference to current document
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  if not Assigned(Doc) then
    Exit;
  // Get parent window of current document
  HTMLWindow := Doc.parentWindow;
  if not Assigned(HTMLWindow) then
    Exit;
  // Run JavaScript
  try
    JSFn := Format('SetFont("%s")', [S]);  // build function call
    HTMLWindow.execScript(JSFn, 'JavaScript'); // execute function
  except
    // handle exception in case JavaScript fails to run
  end;
end;
```

Y para usarlo,

```
CallSentFont("Arial");
```